# Show/hide submenus when clicking next/previous sibling with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a mobile dropdown navigation that needs to have the nested `<ul class="nav-child">` collapse/expand when tapping on the next/previous `<li class="deeper">` expander `<button>`. I have tried using siblings and closest, but with limited JavaScript knowledge, I have not figured out the best way to implement them into this code.

Here is the existing working code:

```js
const toggleSubMenus = (() => {
  let parents = document.querySelectorAll(".deeper");
  parents.forEach(function(parent) {
    let btn = parent.querySelector(".js-expand-submenu");
    let child = parent.querySelector(".nav-child");
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      parent.classList.toggle("is-expanded");
      child.classList.toggle("expanded");
    }, false);
  });
})();
```

```css
ul ul.is-hidden {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul ul.expanded {
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item deeper parent">
    <a href="#">Item One</a>
    <button class="js-expand-submenu">
      Expander
        </button>
    <ul class="nav-child is-hidden">
      <li class="item deeper parent">
        <a href="#">Sub Item One</a>
        <ul class="nav-child is-hidden">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item deeper parent">
    <a href="#">Item Two</a>
    <button class="js-expand-submenu">
      Expander
        </button>
    <ul class="nav-child is-hidden">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item One</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item deeper parent">
    <a href="#">Item Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Taplar I am not sure why the error is occurring here. The code is executing when clicking the buttons with events attached. The in-development version of this code shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code with the solution included:

```js
const toggleSubMenus = (() => {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".js-expand-submenu");
  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let target = e.target;
      let parent = target.closest(".deeper");
      let child = parent.querySelector(".nav-child");
      parent.classList.toggle("is-open");
      child.classList.toggle("is-expanded");
      document.querySelectorAll(".nav-child.is-expanded").forEach(function(childExpanded) {
        if (childExpanded !== child) {
          childExpanded.classList.remove("is-expanded");
        }
      });
    }, false);
  });
})();
```

```css
ul .nav-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul .nav-child.is-expanded {
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item deeper parent">
    <a href="#">Item One</a>
    <button class="js-expand-submenu">
      Expander
        </button>
    <ul class="nav-child">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item One</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item deeper parent">
    <a href="#">Item Two</a>
    <button class="js-expand-submenu">
      Expander
        </button>
    <ul class="nav-child">
      <li class="item deeper parent">
        <a href="#">Sub Item One</a>
        <ul class="nav-child">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item One</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item Two</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Item Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item deeper parent">
    <a href="#">Item Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just a question. Does your solution work with multi-level menus or just 2-level ones? Thanks